# How to change color of the separator in UISplitViewController UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay mode

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I googled all of the related questions , but all the answers are to change color by setting the splitview background color. It did work in `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible` mode ，but not in `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay`. Can anybody help me ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer, Add a 1px line in splitviewcontroller

> _seperateView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)+20)];
>
> _seperateView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seprateLine"]
>
> [self.view insertSubview:_seperateView atIndex:0];

and layout it frame in viewWillLayoutSubviews

> - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
>
> _seperateView.left = _masterNav.view.width + _masterNav.view.left;
>
> }